# ng-model is not showing value

Tags: javascript, scope, angularjs-scope

It's showing value when only I inspect on that textbox

```
<div class="col-sm-2">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label">Equi No:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" ng-model="name" autocomplete="off" />
        <div class="help-block" ng-messages="contentForm.traffic2.$error" role="alert">
        </div>
    </div>    
</div>
```

Input data from name1:

> $scope.name=document.getElementById('name1').value;

But its working for javascript but not for the angular scope

Comment: the way your setting $scope.name seems a little hacky. $scope.name = "Equi No" should work.

Answer (score 0):

you dont need value property . ng-model itself will do the binding for you. when user changes the value the same will be reflected in the controller as it supports two way data binding .
'In yor JS

```
angular.mdoule('app',[]);
angular.module ('app').controller('yourcontrollername',controllername)
mainController.$inject = ['$scope'];
function mainController($scope){

  $scope.ng-model= 'value of the input'

}
```